# How do I connect to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a project I have inherited and need to connect to an AWS EC2 instance. But I can not seem to connect to it. If I go into the EC2 Console, select the instance then connect. I would normally use SSH Client, but if I select this I get the following error:

> No associated key pair
> This instance is not associated with a key pair. Without a key pair, you can't connect to the instance through SSH.

If I try Session Manager I get this error: `We weren't able to connect to your instance`

And If I try EC2 instance connect I get `Failed to Connect to you instance error`.

I only need to run some very basic maintenance tasks and keep this alive for another month or so. So do not want to jump in too deep!

If anyone can help me here would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Here are docs describing how to connect to the instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

Referring to the two methods you mentioned:

1. SSH connection to the instance requires:

- run in a public network
- with Internet Gateway set as a wildcard route in the routing table assigned to the subnet
- with Elastic IP assigned to the instance
- with EC2 key pair added to AWS and assigned to the instance

2. Session manager requires:

- AWS SSM agent running on the instance (it runs on AWS Linux by default, so you might want to change base AMI)
- IAM policiy assigned to the instance role: `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`

Answer (score -1):

Fallow these steps:
Open an SSH client.
Locate your private key file. The key used to launch this instance is `key.pem`
Run this command, if necessary, to ensure your key is not publicly viewable.

```
chmod 400 key.pem
```

Connect to your instance using its Public DNS:

```
 ec2-1-3-2.2.ap-south-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Example:

```
 ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-1-3-2.2.ap-south-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**Go to aws Security Groups edit inbound rules to allow ssh to defult port 22**

*if you have a firewall configured for your server, you must also update the firewall rules to allow access on the new SSH port:*

Comment: there is no key associated with the instance. He won't be able to achieve that.

Comment: You can create new new stance with key(.pem). Don't have other option to access your server without key.